# Facebook Webhook Subscription not showing in Lead Ads Testing Tool

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have subscribed to leadgen topic for my page. Tested it using Webhooks console, it works fine. I created an ad with lead form and tried to create a test lead. But the webhook is not being triggered. What could be the reason?

I'm the admin of the app.

In Lead Ads Testing Tool I'm able to see the below message. When I navigate to Webhooks page I can see that I have already subscribed to leadgen topic.

WEBHOOK SUBSCRIPTION FOR THE SELECTED PAGE
There is no webhook subscription with Lead Ads for the selected page

Comment: Can you share the solution as I am also facing the same issue

Comment: The same issue for me. All pages work fine except the only one

Comment: Any solution , happen to me

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/lead-ads/quickstart/webhooks-integration/ Look at Step 3.  I haven't figured this out yet myself, but this is where you need to start.

Answer (score 0):

You need to subscribe your App to the Facebook Page by sending a POST request to:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{page-id}/subscribed_apps?subscribed_fields=leadgen
```

Note that it requires a Page Access Token (I set this in the Authorization Header), and also requires lead_retrieval, pages_manage_metadata, and pages_show_list permissions.

You can also check whether a page is subscribed to your app by sending a GET request to the same endpoint:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{page-id}/subscribed_apps
```

See [here for more details](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/getting-started/webhooks-for-leadgen#requirements) (including example responses).